# Simple query to find the employee id, date and minimum_time and maximum_time order by id,date,time

Tags: mysql, sql

[image: 9]

How can i find the employee id, date and minimum_time and maximum_time order by id,date,time from this table?

Comment: Please show your expected output.

Comment: id                  date                    in_time            out_time
120721396   2014-01-18        08:24:43          17:13:20

Comment: What have you tried yet ? Please remember that **SO is not a coding service**, we will not write code for you.

Comment: public function get_max_min_sl($emp_id,$datex){
  $result = $this->con()->query("SELECT
  date(tu.date) as Day,
  time(min(tu.time)) as MinTime,
  time(max(tu.time))as MaxTime,tr.sl
FROM tbl_upload tu,tbl_roaster tr
WHERE tu.emp_id = '$emp_id'
AND tu.date = '$datex'
AND tr.emp_id='$emp_id' and tr.date<='$datex' and tr.day=dayofweek('$datex') order by tr.date desc limit 1");
  return $result;
 }

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT emp_id,
       date,
       MIN(time) AS in_time,
       MAX(time) AS out_time
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY emp_id,
         date
ORDER BY emp_id, date
```

The `MIN()` and `MAX()` functions will find the earliest and latest time of each employee, on each date.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple your query syntax would be like

```
SELECT atr1, atr2,.. FROM table_name ORDER BY atr1, atr2,..
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the SELECT Query

```
SELECT employee.id, employee.date, employee.minimum_time, employee.maximum_time 
From table_name
ORDER BY employee.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT  `emp_id` ,  `date` , MIN(  `time` ) as in_time , MAX(  `time` )  as out_time
FROM  `Table` 
WHERE 1 
GROUP BY  `date` 
ORDER BY  `time` DESC 
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

As i can see there are same emp_id for many dates, so group by date will get all data for each date.